# SQL group_concat remove left join

Tags: java, sql, group-concat

I have these two tables

```
 FunctionName | value
 -------------+---------
 intensity    |  0
 status       |  NULL
```

and

```
 FunctionName | StatusName 
 -------------+------------
 status       |  ON        
 status       |  Off
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
    Functions.FunctionName, Functions.value,
    GROUP_CONCAT(FunctionsWithStatus.StatusName)
FROM
    Functions
LEFT JOIN
    FunctionsWithStatus ON Functions.FunctionName = FunctionsWithStatus.Functionsname
```

The result is:

```
Name   | value | group_concat
status | 0     | off,on
```

How can I also retrieve the value of "intensity" and get a result like this:

```
Name      | value | group_concat
intensity |  0    |  NUll
status    |  0    | off,on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  You have mixed unaggregated columns with aggregated columns.  MySQL treats this as an aggregation query with no `group by` -- which returns exactly one row.  The values for the unaggregated columns comes from *indeterminate* rows.

You should include all unaggregated columns in the `group by` (not just a good idea, but standard SQL):

```
select f.FunctionName, f.value, group_concat(fws.StatusName)
from Functions f left join
     FunctionsWithStatus fws
     on f.FunctionName = fws.Functionsname
group by f.FunctionName, f.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Group by` should do the Job:

```
SELECT Functions.FunctionName,Functions.value,group_concat(FunctionsWithStatus.StatusName)
from  Functions
left join  FunctionsWithStatus on Functions.FunctionName = FunctionsWithStatus.Functionsname
Group by Functions.FunctionName
```